# $\sigma$-algebra + measure implies premeasure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

> **Definition:** By a measure $\mu$ on a measurable space
> $\left(X, \mathcal{M}\right)$ we mean an extended real-valued
> nonnegative set function $\mu\colon\mathcal{M}\to[0, \infty]$ for which $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ and which is countably additive.

> **Definition:** Let $S$ be a collection of subsets of a set $X$ and $\mu\colon S\to[0, \infty]$ a set function. Then $\mu$ is called a *premeasure* provided $\mu$ is both finitely additive and countably monotone and, if $\emptyset$ belongs to $S$, then $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$.

> **Question:** Show that if a set function on a $\sigma$-algebra is a measure then it's a premeasure.

Let $\mu\colon\mathcal{M}\to[0,\infty]$ be a measure on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}$.

Firstly, as $\mu$ is a measure, by definition it follows that $\mu(\emptyset)=0$.

Finite additivity immediately follows from countable additivity by setting $E_k = \emptyset$, so that
$μ(E_k) = 0$, for $k > n$.

For countable monotonicity, let $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be any countable collection of measurable that covers a measurable set $E$. Define $F_1 = E_1$ and then define

$$F_n = E_k\setminus\left[\bigcup_{i=1}^{k-1}E_i\right]\text{ for } k\geq 2.$$

Immediately, it's seen that

$$\{F_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}\text{ is disjoint, } \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}F_k = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k\text{ and } F_k\subseteq E_k\text{ for every } k.$$

From countable additivity and monotonicity of $\mu$ being measure,

$$\mu(E)\leq\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k\right)=\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}F_k\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(F_k)\leq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_k).$$

---

Is this correct? Also, I'm not sure the fact that $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra comes in?

Comment: The fact that $\mathcal M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra is needed so that you can talk about measures or premeasures. C.f. definitions of measures and premeasures.

Comment: @WhatsUp: So is it not needed to justify the $F_n$'s belong to $\mathcal{M}$ in order to apply countably additivity and such? That is, since $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra it is closed with respect to relative compliments so indeed each $F_n$ belongs to $\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: It is needed, and in fact it is needed even before you say "let $\mu$ be a measure" as the definition of a measure requires that it is defined on a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @WhatsUp: Ah okay, thanks! So, does the solution look correct then to show that $\mu$ is a premeasure?

Comment: I'm not sure which definition of premeasure are you taking. According to [my knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-measure), the definition of a premeasure doesn't involve countable monotonicity.

Comment: @WhatsUp: The one I'm using is from Roydens text, and from what I've read/heard he follows a different def. of premeasure. I've included it

Comment: That is possible. I don't have Roydens text. I suggest that you include also the definition of a measure for clarity.

Comment: @WhatsUp: I've included it, and the use of monotonicity in my proof is derived from the definition of of a measure.

Comment: I see. Yes, your proof looks good, and $\mathcal M$ being $\sigma$-algebra is used here to ensure that the $F$'s are all in $\mathcal M$.

Comment: @WhatsUp: Great! Thanks for the conformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. It can be made a little shorter.

> **Definition:** By a measure $\mu$ on a measurable space
> $\left(X, \mathcal{M}\right)$ we mean an extended real-valued
> nonnegative set function $\mu\colon\mathcal{M}\to[0, \infty]$ for which $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ and which is countably additive.

> **Definition:** Let $S$ be a collection of subsets of a set $X$ and $\mu\colon S\to[0, \infty]$ a set function. Then $\mu$ is called a *premeasure* provided $\mu$ is both finitely additive and countably monotone and, if $\emptyset$ belongs to $S$, then $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$.

> **Question:** Show that if a set function on a $\sigma$-algebra is a measure then it's a premeasure.

**Proof**: Let $\mu\colon\mathcal{M}\to[0,\infty]$ be a measure on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}$.

Firstly, as $\mu$ is a measure, by definition it follows that $\mu(\emptyset)=0$.

Finite additivity immediately follows from countable additivity by setting $E_k = \emptyset$, so that
$μ(E_k) = 0$, for $k > n$.

For countable monotonicity, let $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be any countable collection of measurable that covers a measurable set $E$.

Since $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we have that $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k \in \mathcal{M}$. Since $\mu$ is a measure defined on $\mathcal{M}$, we have
$$\mu(E)\leq\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k\right)\leq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_k)$$
(you don't need to go through the sets $F_n$).